# AJAX request json fail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a problem with an ajax request, when I do the request with the property dataType: 'json', my response come with an error, parsererror, my function in PHP returns the data like json_encode(), pls, can you help me? when I do the request without property dataType: 'json' my data is ALL THE DOCUMENT HTML.

My request:

```
                var dataAr = {Latitude: Latitude, Longitude: Longitude};/
                console.log(dataAr);
                $.ajax({
                    data: dataAr,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/GPS/Server.php/GPS/Coords',
                    success: function (data, response) {
                        console.log('Data: '+data);
                        console.log('Response: '+response);

                    },
                    error: function  (textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('Status: '+textStatus);
                        console.log('Error: '+errorThrown);                            
                    }
                });
```

My function in PHP:

```
class GPS 
{
    function Coords()
    {
        $Res=$_POST['data'];
        $Latitude=$_POST['Latitude'];
        $Longitude=$_POST['Longitude'];

        return json_encode($Res);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using echo to send the data back to your Ajax function?

Comment: @bobdye With the echo in my function PHP happens the same error

Comment: inspect actual request in browser console network tab. I suspect your routing isn't right either

Comment: @charlietfl are you talking about my URL? i don't think so but thanks for the comment, i tested my request just in a native code like 'server.php' without the class and function and... does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try using `content-type` :

```
function Coords()
{
    $Res=$_POST['data'];
    $Latitude=$_POST['Latitude'];
    $Longitude=$_POST['Longitude'];

    header('Content-Type: application/json'); // <-- HERE
    return json_encode($Res);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The $_POST variables have the same names at what you send in, not 'data'. It's not clear what you are trying to return, so for example purposes the following just returns and array with the input values:

```
class GPS 
{
    function Coords()
    {
    $Latitude=$_POST['Latitude'];
    $Longitude=$_POST['Longitude'];
    $result = array( $Latitude, $longitude );

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);            
    }
}
```